# Can I implement IF EXIST with a given file extension?

Tags: windows, batch, file-extension, conditional-statements

I'm in the process of making a batch script to autoexecute a program if a given file type (in this case specifically `*.iso`) is found. Here is the current direction I'm headed:

```bat
IF EXIST *.iso GOTO :AUTORUN

:AUTORUN
"Impot.exe" "*.iso"
```

I know my current code will not do this, so I want to know if this is possible, and how to properly program my script to auto execute if a disc image is found.

Answer (score 2):

`dir` returns a non-zero exit code if the files are not found

So you just need to check the error level

```bat
dir *.iso >NUL 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 "Impot.exe" "*.iso"
```

or simply

```bat
dir *.iso >NUL 2>&1 || "Impot.exe" "*.iso"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forfiles` utility included with Windows:

```
forfiles /S /M *.iso /P \Path\where\to\start /C "cmd /c Impot.exe @path"
```

If you don't need to search iso files recursively then remove option `/S`

Comment: note that the behavior of this is different. It calls `Impot.exe` separately for each file found and not passing the wildcard directly to the executable